# How to limit image size in Cloud Storage for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Cloud Storage for Firebase rule like this.

```
 service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read;
          allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        }
      }
    }
```

But I can still upload image greater than 1MB.

How I can prevent user upload image file greater than 1MB.

I upload image using the Admin SDK.

Comment: From where are you uploading the image? Client app? Firebase console?

Comment: I upload the image from express Nodejs using admin.storage.bucket.upload().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Admin SDK, you totally bypass the security rules for the different Firebase services (you have "full admin privileges").

This means that you have to implement this check on the file size **in your Node.js server**, before uploading the file to Cloud Storage.